# Android Toggle Button in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, togglebutton

Is there a way to put a ToggleButton in the ActionBar and get it to save what state it is in, so when you open the same activity again it is in the same state as you left it?

Extra:
If possible have android 2.3.3 - 2.3.7 backward compatibility

Answer (score 2):

First define a **layout** that contains your Toggle:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_service_toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="Logging On"
    android:textOff="Logging Off" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you have two alternatives to proceed:

**Using an action layoput:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/myswitch"
        android:title=""
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_service_toggle" />   
</menu>
```

**Inflating programmatically:**
In your **Activity** or **Fragment** you do:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_top);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
...
ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_service_toggle);
```

Comment: To get this to work, I had to use `app:showAsAction="always"` and `app:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_service_toggle"` - with the `app` namespace declared as `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActionBar.setCustomView()` and pass it a `Switch` or `ToggleButton`, though I don't know if this will work alongside other ActionBar navigation modes. As for saving this value, just store it's checked state in SharedPreferences and set it again when the Activity gets created.

As for backwards compatibility, you have two options: [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library, or Google's new [v7 support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).